# Thunderbolt 3 not working on ASUS ZenBook Pro UX501VW

Tags: laptop, bios, thunderbolt, asus, zenbook

I'm trying to connect a docking station to my laptop via Thunderbolt 3 to connect my monitors, but they aren't connecting. I'm pretty sure I need to update the Thunderbolt Drivers & BIOS for my laptop.

How do I make sure my Thunderbolt 3 is working? Here's something from my device manager (a lot of unknowns): https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIAAJ.png

Do you think I should follow this article's instructions?: https://kb.cablematters.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=63
I already installed the latest Thunderbolt driver for my laptop, but I think I have to update BIOS now?

Here's where I bought the laptop: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B018AX3OHO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018AX3OHO)
I boot Windows 11 on it as well, so maybe it's an OS issue?

Comment: Do all windows updates, then reboot. Then do that again. Then make a screenshot of device manager and post it here. All unknown devices should be recognized. If not, let us know which.

Comment: Yeah I already checked for Windows Updates, nothing else to update apparently. Do you mean install all the drivers that the article mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, if Windows update can no longer find more drivers for you then you should do as the cablematters article says (I doubt you'll have to update the BIOS tho, skip that for now)

Comment: You probably will have to update UEFI ("BIOS") and install the most up-to-date drivers/firmware for Thunderbolt.

Comment: I update both the XGA and the thunderbolt drivers and my docking station is working! Can hook up my monitors . But I didn't update the Intel graphics driver nor the BIOS (tbh I didn't want to mess with the BIOS lol)

Comment: Also, I still get those unknown devices on my device manager (see photo from post), which is weird. I'm also thinking of allocating more memory from my RAM for my GPU and see if it'll boost performance (since it sort of lags when I play multiple videos on multiple monitors)